# Laravel 5 Eloquent Condition (IN)

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following Model Relationship

Models

Sector - [id, name]

Location - [id, sector_id, name]

Sector has many locations

Location belongs to sector

```
class Location extends Model {
    public function sector() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sector');
    }
}
```

I want to make the following query using Laravel 5 Eloquent

SELECT * FROM `locations` WHERE `sector_id` IN (1,2,3)

I tried,

$location->where('sector_id', 'in', [1,2,3])

But no any records were returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `whereIn` method and use the `get` method at the end to actually fetch the objects from DB, like this:

```
$locations = App\Location::whereIn('sector_id', [1,2,3])->get();
```